# Using multiprocessing.Pool in Python with a function returning custom object

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, pickle, python-multiprocessing

I am using multiprocessing.Pool to speed up computation, as I call one function multiple times, and then collate the result. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
import multiprocessing
from functools import partial

def Foo(id:int,constant_arg1:str, constant_arg2:str):
    custom_class_obj = CustomClass(constant_arg1, constant_arg2)
    custom_class_obj.run() # this changes some attributes of the custom_class_obj
    
    if(something):
       return None
    else:
       return [custom_class_obj]



def parallel_run(iters:int, a:str, b:str):
  pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=k)

  ## create the partial function obj before passing it to pool
  partial_func = partial(Foo, constant_arg1=a, constant_arg2=b)

  ## create the variable id list
  iter_list = list(range(iters))
  all_runs = pool.map(partial_func, iter_list)
 
  return all_runs
```

This throws the following error in the multiprocessing module:

```
multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '[[<CustomClass object at 0x1693c7070>], [<CustomClass object at 0x1693b88e0>], ....]'
Reason: 'TypeError("cannot pickle 'module' object")'
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You'd need to make your custom class pickleable. That error however suggests that you're trying to return the *module*, not a custom class.

Comment: I am returning a CustomClass object (as seen in the list shown after 'result' in the error message). But, is there a way to use Pool for classes that are not pickleable?

Comment: You're going to have to post your `CustomClass`. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to replicate the error message with a minimal example of an un-picklable class. The error basically states the instance of your class can't be pickled because it contains a reference to a module, and modules are not picklable. You need to comb through `CustomClass` to make sure instances don't hold things like open file handles, module references, etc.. If you need to have those things, you should use `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` to [customize the pickle and unpickle process](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#handling-stateful-objects).

distilled example of your error:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial

class klass:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.value = a
        import os
        self.module = os #this fails: can't pickle a module and send it back to main process

def foo(a, b, c):
    return klass(a+b+c)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with Pool() as p:
        a = 1
        b = 2
        bar = partial(foo, a, b)
        res = p.map(bar, range(10))
    print([r.value for r in res])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, my class does have module references. In fact it explicitly contains a 'Program' class object which internally contains a python program file. But setting __getstate__ and __setstate__ functions for the class is proving to be tricky. Is there an alternate work around solution using 'dill' serializer?

Comment: I've not done this, but a cheap hack could possibly be to call `dill` to serialize `self` inside `__getstate__` and deserialize inside `__setstate__`. There's also the `pathos` library which I have also not worked with, but I'm aware it uses `dill` for some things

Comment: maybe also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40245339/3220135)