# Monkey patching cloudpickle as multiprocessing pickler

Tags: python-multiprocessing, multiprocess, cloudpickle

I am trying to use [PyDREAM](https://github.com/LoLab-VU/PyDREAM) to sample a likelihood that has a number of dynamically constructed elements, i.e., class factories. The class factories are pretty necessary, so making the likelihood function easier to pickle is not really an option. This doesn't have much to do with `PyDREAM`, as there are a number of "out of the box" samplers that use pickling of some sort for multiprocessing. I assume this is pretty standard since the pickling happens in the `multiprocessing` module. I'd like to figure out if there is a way to make them work with my code. I was really excited to find `cloudpickle` which can successfully pickle my likelihood function.

I recently forked `PyDREAM` and tried this [monkey patch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66027412/8792791). I have successfully patched `cloudpickle` in, but `multiprocessing` is trying to call a method called `register`, which does not seem to exist in `cloudpickle`. I know nothing about the inner workings of these picklers. There are other methods that start with "register" in `cloudpickle`, but they don't seem quite right.

```
~/anaconda3/envs/dream/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/sharedctypes.py in rebuild_ctype(type_, wrapper, length)
    136     if length is not None:
    137         type_ = type_ * length
--> 138     _ForkingPickler.register(type_, reduce_ctype)
    139     buf = wrapper.create_memoryview()
    140     obj = type_.from_buffer(buf)

AttributeError: type object 'CloudPickler' has no attribute 'register'
```

Also, I've tried using `dill` to serialize the likelihood with no luck. It would be awesome if `multiprocess` allowed the use of `cloudpickle`, and there is an [issue](https://github.com/uqfoundation/multiprocess/issues/22) on the `multiprocess` GitHub page about this, but it doesn't seem to be a feature that is being actively worked on.

Comment: Pathos is a library that has a drop in replacement for multiprocessing that uses dill. I would just use that instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Hi @CJR Thanks for the comment! As I said in the post, I have tried `dill` with no luck unfortunately.

Comment: I'm the `dill` author.  `pathos`/`multirprocess` uses `dill`  Did you try to use the `cloudpickle`-like setting on `dill` (i.e. `dill.settings['recurse'] = True`)?  If that doesn't work for you, then you might want to consider filing a GitHub issue for `dill` detailing what you tried to do to serialize the likelihood.